# How to load h2 database from geonetwork in netbeans?

Tags: geonetwork

I'm using Geonetwork 2.10.3. I have all needed files and i want to connect to h2 database in NetBeans, so I could add new language. Howerver, I can't connect to h2. I have followed these steps:
1. In Services tab, Right-Click on Databases and click New Connection;
2. In new window, in in padded menu, i have chosen New Driver and added .jar file from lib folder named h2-1.3.152.jar, and then Next;
3. I have typed user and pass in fields, url fieled has been filled with jdbc:h2:, and then Next.

After that, it throws me exception:
 Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:h2:  using org.h2.Driver (IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ .lock.db (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"; "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ .lock.db" [90031-152]).
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a file right issue. H2 cannot create the lock file in the specified folder. You have to specify a file for the database stored in a folder that does not require administrator rights. "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\" is usually protected by windows.

Solution, specify an url relative to user folder:

`jdbc:h2:~/test`

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461770/where-does-h2s-embedded-databases-store-the-data

Note: This question is not related to H2GIS.